# Group by name and add up the columns count in r

Tags: r, string

I have a dataset with 405 observations and 39 variables. But just two columns are important for further analysis.

I would like to group the first row with similar names together and add up their number from the second column.

Reproducible dataset looks like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(name=c("Google Ads", "Google Doubleclick","Facebook Login",
"Facebook Ads","Twitter MoPub","Flurry","Amazon advertisment","Microsoft ","Ad4screen","imobi"),
value=c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100),unimportant=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
```

Outcome should be in an new data.frame and look like this:

```
 df2 <- data.frame (name=c("Google","Facebook","Twitter","Flurry","Amazon","Microsoft","Others"),
value=c(30,70,50,60,70,80,190))
```

Comment: How do we determine which rows are important? i.e. how do we interpret the 1:10 values for `unimportant`? Thank you

Comment: just the name and value column is important . the unimportant column is not important.

Comment: what's the criteria for `others`.? For other groups it seems first name?  Is it?  how to group some string like `something microsoft` into `something` or into `microsoft`?

Comment: it would be the one word inside of the string (no matter which position in the string) -the word where I´m searching for are saved in df2$name. The criteria for the group others is to have no matching word from df2$names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `tidyverse` way of doing it.

- First store all valid_names in a vector say `valid_names`
- Thereafter create a new column say `all_names` in `df1` by -

  - first splitting all strings at space `' '` using `str_split`
  - thereafter use `purrr::map_chr()` to check if any of the split string matches with your `valid_names` and if yes, retrieve that string only otherwise get `others`
- Thereafter `group_by` on this field.  (I omitted one step of mutate first and then `group_by` and directly created the new field in group_by statement, that works)
- Now summarise your `important` values as desired.

```r
valid_names =c("Google","Facebook","Twitter","Flurry","Amazon","Microsoft")

valid_names
#> [1] "Google"    "Facebook"  "Twitter"   "Flurry"    "Amazon"    "Microsoft"

df1 <- data.frame(name=c("Google Ads", "Google Doubleclick","Facebook Login",
                         "Facebook Ads","Twitter MoPub","Flurry","Amazon advertisment","Microsoft ","Ad4screen","imobi"),
                  value=c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100),unimportant=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
df1
#>                   name value unimportant
#> 1           Google Ads    10           1
#> 2   Google Doubleclick    20           2
#> 3       Facebook Login    30           3
#> 4         Facebook Ads    40           4
#> 5        Twitter MoPub    50           5
#> 6               Flurry    60           6
#> 7  Amazon advertisment    70           7
#> 8           Microsoft     80           8
#> 9            Ad4screen    90           9
#> 10               imobi   100          10
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>% group_by(all_names = str_split(name, ' '),
               all_names = map_chr(all_names, ~ ifelse(any(.x %in% valid_names),.x[.x %in% valid_names], 'others'))) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(value), .groups = 'drop')
#> # A tibble: 7 x 2
#>   all_names value
#>   <chr>     <dbl>
#> 1 Amazon       70
#> 2 Facebook     70
#> 3 Flurry       60
#> 4 Google       30
#> 5 Microsoft    80
#> 6 others      190
#> 7 Twitter      50
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This works on the sample data using the `adist` function and with `partial=TRUE` to look at partial string matches. It requires defining the known groups though, rather than trying to find them. I think this leg work is worth doing though as it simplifies the problem a lot once the output is known

```
df1 <- data.frame(name=c("Google Ads", "Google Doubleclick","Facebook Login",
                         "Facbook Ads","Twitter MoPub","Flurry","Amazon advertisment","Microsoft ","Ad4screen","imobi"),
                  value=c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100),unimportant=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))

# types we want to map. known is the groupings
types <- unique(df1$name)
known <- c("Google","Facebook","Twitter","Flurry","Amazon","Microsoft")

# use distrance measures, and look for matches on partial strings eg
# ignore the Doubleclick part when matching on Google
distance <- adist(known, types, partial=TRUE)

# cap controls leniancy in matching e.g. Facbook and Facebook have a dist of 1
# whilst Facebook and Facebook is a perfect match with score of 0
# Raise to be more leniant
cap <- 1
# loop through the types
map_all <- sapply(seq_along(types), function(i){
  # find minimum value, check if its below the cap. If so, assign to the closest
  # group, else assign to others
  v <- min(distance[,i])
  if(v <= cap){
    map_i <- known[which.min(distance[,i])]
  }else{
    map_i <- "Others"
  }
  map_i
})

# now merge in to df1, then sum out using your preferred method
df_map <- data.frame(name=types, group=map_all)
df_merged <- merge(df1, df_map, by="name")
df2 <- aggregate(value ~ group, sum, data=df_merged)
df2
      group value
1    Amazon    70
2  Facebook    70
3    Flurry    60
4    Google    30
5 Microsoft    80
6    Others   190
7   Twitter    50
```